# Changing Numbers even after page loads?

Tags: php, javascript, html

how can i get numbers changing on html page even after page loads.

what i mean is i have a site where i want to show **users online** so after page loads, the numbers should change after specific milliseconds without refreshing the page , how can i do that ?

and can those numbers be from a range ? like from 700 to 990

in html or php or javascript anything will work.

---

**update for those jumping in and saying use math rand, please read the question again.**

**you are not getting my question,** 
i know i can generate random numbers but thats not what i want.
what i want is changing numbers , 
surfer comes to my site and he sees numbers changing on web page, much like animated gif image.

thanks

Comment: Do you just want to show a random fake number, or actual users online ?

Comment: If you want to show the real number of online users, then increase session by 1 each time the user log ins. Then use javascript set_interval function along with ajax to automatically load page where it echo's number of online users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue Solved here is an answer

you can do something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/ZDsMa/94/

with this code

```
var output, started, duration, desired;

// Constants
duration = 5000;
desired = '50';

// Initial setup
output = $('#output');
started = new Date().getTime();

// Animate!
animationTimer = setInterval(function() {
    // If the value is what we want, stop animating
    // or if the duration has been exceeded, stop animating
    if (output.text().trim() === desired || new Date().getTime() - started > duration) {
        console.log('animating');
        // Generate a random string to use for the next animation step
        output.text('' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 990)

        );

    } else {
        console.log('animating');
        // Generate a random string to use for the next animation step
        output.text('' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 990)

        );
    }
}, 1000);
```

i know the code isnt perfect but it does the trick i have modified some other code.

thaks

Answer (score 2):

Just try this :

```
setInterval(generate_random_number,2000);
function generate_random_number()
{
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*11)
    return number;
}
```

where 11 dictates that the random number will fall between 0-10. To increase the range to, say, 100, simply change 11 to 101 instead.

setInterval function will call generate_random_number function every 2 seconds and after that do whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

use javascript for this purpose:

Use `Math.random();` to get a random number between 0 to 1.

process to get desired range accordingly.

then use javascript to change the inner html of the element containing the number.

i.e. `document.getElementById('ID OF THE ELEMENT').innerHTML = 'THE NUMBER OBTAINED FORM THE ABOVE PROCESSING';`

and yes one more thing use Interval methods for the every number of seconds

i.e. : `setInterval`